# Why does TFS only support 1-to-many Predecessor /Successor relationships?

Tags: tfs

The TFS task tracker only supports 1-to-many Predecessor/Successor relationships ([docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/link-type-reference?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fboards%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fboards%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json%20toc.json&view=azure-devops)).

I totally do not understand why is so.

For me it's obviously a many-to-many relationship, since a task may be blocked by more than one predecessor tasks.

This is the first and only time I've seen such a restriction in such a tracker (for instance, Meistertask supports many-to-many).

Since I can't think of any technical problem to do that (it should be trivial), I'm pretty sure there is a real reason for that. I'd just like to know that reason: I guess it's public, but I couldn't find it.

**Note: this is not a rant**. This is **a very specific question**, that may very well have a known answer (although it's possible it doesn't). If you think this is a rant either you misread it, or I miswrote it, or a combination of both.

Answer (score 1):

Because this link has direction from one side to another. Only one work item can on the start of this direction. However, work item:

1. Can has many successor
2. Can has many predecessor.

This type of link can not create the cycle, like:

1. Wi1 successor to WI2
2. Wi2 successor to WI1